# Dockerfile Installing Selenium - Ambiguous code

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-firefoxdriver

Can someone explain this code to me?

```
# Installation required for selenium
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y tzdata ca-certificates bzip2 curl wget libc-dev libxt6 \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y `apt-cache depends firefox-esr | awk '/Depends:/{print$2}'` \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    # Cleanup unnecessary stuff
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove \
                  -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*
```

Why is it necessary to put this in a Dockerfile for selenium to run? (tested and won't run without the code). Why doesn't it simply work by using pip to install the selenium dependency?

**Source:** [Firefox(headless)+selenium cannot access internet from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118544/firefoxheadlessselenium-cannot-access-internet-from-docker-container)

Comment: Which image are you using

Comment: apologies, i don't know anything about docker and thus don't understand your question. Just trying to get my script deployed to the web

Comment: There is something called , from a

Comment: `FROM python:3.8` ?